# How to setup intellij-idea to understands table names in hibernate XML files

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij 9 and Hibernate. Everything works fine, however Intellij does not detect table names in *.hbm.xml files. I've setup hibernate facet and everything else is recognized by intellij (links between hbm.xml files and corresponding classes are working). Just the table name and column name is not get resolved by Intellij. What did I miss in setting up the intellij? Do I need to somehow bind the intellij to the MySql which I'm using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [Data Source](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/data-sources-and-drivers-dialog.html) configured for the project.

Answer (score 2):

Either you can turn off that resolution.

Go to:

> Settings -> Inspections -> Java EE issues -> Data Source ORM
>   Annotation problems

And select the severity you desire ('*warning*' for instance). 
Also see [intellij documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-inspection-severities.html).